# Azure blob container mounting to AKS deployment error

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-aks

Events:
Type     Reason              Age                From                     Message

---

Normal   Scheduled           44s                default-scheduler        Successfully assigned fcc-poc/fccapp-5cd844c68d-55gpc to aks-l21d11107014-59385960-vmss00007d
Warning  FailedAttachVolume  10s (x7 over 44s)  attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "afs-fcc-appdata" : Retriable: false, RetryAfter: 0s, HTTPStatusCode: 400, RawError: Retriable: false, RetryAfter: 0s, HTTPStatusCode: 400, RawError: {
"error": {
"code": "InvalidParameter",
"message": "Required parameter 'dataDisk.managedDisk' is missing (null).",
"target": "dataDisk.managedDisk"
}
}

Comment: Can you please let me know which document you are following?

Comment: I was referring to multiple document especially MS documents.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-storage
Apart from this document I created PV since I don't need to go with dynamic provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce your required scenario and I am able to mount the file share to AKS Pod with static provisioning.

In azure only we can mount the file share or Azure Managed disk to the AKS pod with the help of PV and the document you were referring is for the same use.

[image]

Please follow the below steps to get it apply.

**Step 1: Create an Azure file share Azure file share**

```
 # Change these four parameters as needed for your own environment
AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=rahulstorageaccount7735
AKS_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP=v-ra&&1*-Mi*****
AKS_PERS_LOCATION=eastus
AKS_PERS_SHARE_NAME=aksshare

# Create a resource group
#az group create --name $AKS_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --location $AKS_PERS_LOCATION

# Create a storage account
az storage account create -n $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME -g $AKS_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP -l $AKS_PERS_LOCATION --sku Standard_LRS

# Export the connection string as an environment variable, this is used when creating the Azure file share
export AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=$(az storage account show-connection-string -n $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME -g $AKS_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP -o tsv)

# Create the file share
az storage share create -n $AKS_PERS_SHARE_NAME --connection-string $AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING

# Get storage account key
STORAGE_KEY=$(az storage account keys list --resource-group $AKS_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --account-name $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --query "[0].value" -o tsv)

# Echo storage account name and key
echo Storage account name: $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME
echo Storage account key: $STORAGE_KEY
```

**Step 2 : Create a Kubernetes secret**

```
kubectl create secret generic azure-secret --from-literal=azurestorageaccountname=$AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --from-literal=azurestorageaccountkey=$STORAGE_KEY
```

A Kubernetes secret is also created that includes Storage Account Key.Fetch the secrets using the below command.

```
kubectl get secrets
```

[image]

**Step 3: Mount file share as an persistent volume**

To mount the Azure Files share into your pod, configure the volume in the container spec.
To update your mount options, create a **azurefile-mount-options-pv.yaml** file with a PersistentVolume. For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: azurefile
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  azureFile:
    secretName: azure-secret
    shareName: aksshare
    readOnly: false
  mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
  - mfsymlinks
  - nobrl
```

Create a **azurefile-mount-options-pvc.yaml** file with a PersistentVolumeClaim that uses the PersistentVolume. For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: azurefile
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Use the kubectl commands to create the PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim.

```
kubectl apply -f azurefile-mount-options-pv.yaml
kubectl apply -f azurefile-mount-options-pvc.yaml
```

Create a **app-pod.yaml** file with mypod for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/nginx/nginx:1.15.5-alpine
    name: mypod
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 128Mi
      limits:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 256Mi
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azure
        mountPath: /mnt/azure
  volumes:
  - name: azure
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: azurefile
    # azureFile:
      # secretName: azure-secret
      # shareName: aksshare
      # readOnly: false
```

Deploy sample Nginx Pod and attach it to the File Share

```
kubectl apply -f app-pod.yaml
```

[image]

---

```
# Test access to File Share from the Pod: 
   kubectl exec pod/nginx -it -- /bin/sh
# From inside the Pod shell:
# ls /mnt/azure
# echo "Hello from Azure File Share" > /mnt/azure/myfile.txt
# ls /mnt/azure
# cat /mnt/azure/myfile.txt
```

OutPut : Uploaded a file from Azure portal and can see the file over pod.Hence It has mounted successfully
[image]

[image]

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume
https://github.com/HoussemDellai/aks-file-share

Comment: I think there was an update that requires `storageClassName: azurefile-csi` to make this work.  Go to the referenced link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume) for updates